# Java, non-blocking console output

Tags: java, logging, console

I have an interface which methods are getting called in the multiple threads:

```
interface Handler{
 void readedMessage(long atTime);
 void recievedMessage(long atTime);
 void deletedMessage(long atTime);
}
```

And of course I don't want these callings to block my threads, what I want is just to print something on console where these methods are getting called, to do that I need to implement this interface, what's the best way to do it: are Java loggers provide such functionality or I should make a ThreadExecutor with these prints getting called? It's a simple maven project which will be used as library, so wouldn't it be unecessary to add logger? And which one provides such functionality (googling didn't help unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

> are Java loggers provide such functionality?

Yes, Log4j allows asynchronous writes only by activating them in the runtime, e.g.

```
-Dlog4j2.contextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
```

For further information [Asynchronous Loggers for Low-Latency Logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)